# Are almost all continuous functions nowhere differentiable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The question is mostly in the title, but to be precise, the space is $E={\cal C}^0( [0,1],\mathbb R)$, and 1) is there a reasonably natural measure on $E$ (at least invariant by translation, say) 2) for that measure, is it true that the set of nowhere differentiable continuous functions is of measure 1 ?

Comment: [There aren't any nontrivial translation-invariant measures on $E$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure).  However, in some sense a "natural" measure on $E$ is [Wiener measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space#Classical_Wiener_measure), the distribution of Brownian motion, and it is a classical fact that Brownian motion is a.s. nowhere differentiable, which is to say that Wiener-a.e. continuous function is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Another classical fact is that the nowhere differentiable functions are comeager in $E$; giving you a different sense of the phrase "almost all".

Comment: Thanks a lot ; the fact that the answer was in Wikipedia shows, alas, how hard it is to look for an answer when you dont know how the right concept is named